# Change elements height not working on second push

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I've got a button(#nav-button) that increases an elements height. But I want the same button to also decrease the height when pressed again. The code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

        $('.nav-button-open').click(function(){
            $('.nav-bar').animate({height:'90px'}, 500);
            $("#nav-button").attr('class', 'nav-button-close');
        });
        $('.nav-button-close').click(function(){
            $('.nav-bar').animate({height:'10px'}, 500);
            $("#nav-button").attr('class', 'nav-button-open');
        });
    });​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdecler/e4XED/

The jQuery increases  the height fine but I cannot decrease the height when I press the button again! What am I doing wrong?

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider changing your jQuery code to:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#nav-button').click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("nav-button-open")){
               $('.nav-bar').animate({height:'90px'}, 500);
               $("#nav-button").attr('class', 'nav-button-close');}
            else{
               $('.nav-bar').animate({height:'10px'}, 500);
               $("#nav-button").attr('class', 'nav-button-open');            
            }
        });
    });​
```

DEMO LINK:

http://jsfiddle.net/e4XED/4/

Comment: One small issue though, is it me or do I need to press the button twice before I can use it?

Comment: Hmm, It seemed to work as intended for me. What browser/version are you using?

Comment: And what version of jQuery as well? Those few tid-bits of information may help us figure out what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

As I think, you should use 
    .live('click', ...), because you change your buttons' classes dynamicly, but set click event only at start. [Correct jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdecler/e4XED/).

Comment: `live` is deprecated, you have to use `on` for that now. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `nav-button-close` class does not exist when the jQuery script is loaded. Use `on`.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4XED/3/)

Note: don't use `live`, it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Like aleksey said, use live.  Or you can just add a class and check to see if it exists. 
like:

```
$('.nav-button').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('open')){
            $('.nav-bar').animate({height:'10px'}, 500);
            $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('close');
        }else{
            $('.nav-bar').animate({height:'90px'}, 500);
            $(this).removeClass('close').addClass('open');                 
        }1
    });
```